# Implement a Facebook login without breaking the privacy

Tags: 7, users, social-network

Like everybody knows Facebook ignores the privacy compleatly.

So I would like to allow users to login via Facebook without breaking their privacy or non Facebook users. Curriently I'm using the modules `Fbconnect`, `OpenID Selector`, `OpenID Selector for Drupal login` and `OpenID Selector for Facebook Connect`.

I want to allow the users to log in like in stack exchange. This works almost so like expected except the Facebook stuff. The plugin adds to everypage a stupid link to Facebook. So Facebook can spy my users. How can I avoid that?

Is it possible that I download the `http://connect.facebook.net/xx_XX/all.js` script and put it on my space? Or maybe to proxy the access and cache the file. Does anyone know if some of my ideas are forbidden by Facebook?

Comment: Hi Rekire, I can suggest you a module called Janrain engage http://drupal.org/project/rpx , this does not add links, it helps you during the registration to collect the user data as well. Have a look to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you a module called Janrain engage drupal.org/project/rpx , this does not add links, it helps you during the registration to collect the user data as well. Have a look to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really care about your users privacy then you shouldn't use a third party service like Janrain but instead communicate directly with the Facebook API. You can do that with the [OAuth Connector](http://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector) module for Drupal 7 as it supports signing up and logging in through OAuth 2 API:s and specifically states that Facebook is one of the API:s that works with it.

Comment: I will check this. Janrain is not the best option but I doesn't want that the clients will load any ressources from facebook directly.

Comment: Could you add some more advice how to setup that module? The documentation is not very helpful.

Comment: I have no hands on experience with configuring the current version - I built the original version, but others are maintaining it now. The way it used to work was that you added a couple of services you wanted users to be able to log in with and then placed a block with all log in buttons in the place of your site where you wanted them to appear. Any specific thing you're wondering about?